# ScrollController Not Working Showing Values As Expected

Tags: flutter, dart, scrollcontroller

So I have this `RefreshIndicator()` which requires `RefreshController` and a child which is `SinglechildScrollView()` and I need to add scrollController in it to be able to manipulate the showing and hiding of a widget when a certain position in the screen is met. As below.

```
...
ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
...
bool showFloatingCategories = false;
...
@override
  void initState() {
   
    scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

...

void _scrollListener() {
    // Get the current scroll position
    double scrollPosition = scrollController.position.pixels;

    // Check if the scroll position is greater than or equal to 200
    if (scrollPosition >= 200) {
      // Scroll position is at or beyond 200, you can show/hide widgets here
      setState(() {
        showFloatingCategories = true; // Set your showFloatingCategories flag accordingly
      });
    } else {
      // Scroll position is less than 200
      print(scrollPosition);
      setState(() {
        showFloatingCategories = false; // Set your showFloatingCategories flag accordingly
      });
    }
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: AppTaste.whiteThemeColor,
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            backgroundColor: AppTaste.whiteThemeColor,
            elevation: 0.4,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {


              },
                child: Image.asset('assets/images/airduka_logo_blue.png', height: 35.0,)),
           
          ),
          body: SmartRefresher(
            controller: refreshController,
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            onRefresh: () async {
              final result = await getAllProducts(isRefresh: true);
              //final categoriyResult = await get
              if (result) {
                refreshController.refreshCompleted();
              } else {
                refreshController.refreshFailed();
              }
            },
            onLoading: () async {
              final result = await getAllProducts();
              if (result) {
                refreshController.loadComplete();
              } else {
                refreshController.loadFailed();
              }
            },
            enablePullUp: true,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: scrollController,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 15.0,
                    ),

                    SmallTextWidget(
                      text: categoryName,
                      color: AppTaste.secondaryThemeColor,
                      size: 18.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10.0,
                    ),
                    inventoryList.length >= 1
                        ? GridView.builder(
                         physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: inventoryList.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                            childAspectRatio: 0.8,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 5.0),
                        itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                          var inventoryProduct = inventoryList[index];
                          final _isSelected = _selectedIndex.contains(inventoryProduct.id);
                          return ProductCardWidget(
                              index,
                              inventoryProduct
                                  .product!.featuredImage!.digitalOceanUrl
                                  .toString(),
                              //productCategorySnapshot.data[index]['company']['name'].toString(),
                              inventoryProduct.product!.title.toString(),
                              'KES${double.parse(inventoryProduct.sellingPrice.toString()).toStringAsFixed(0)}'
                                  .replaceAllMapped(reg, mathFunc),
                              inventoryProduct.discount == null
                                  ? ''
                                  : '${double.parse((inventoryProduct.discount! / inventoryProduct.cost! * 100).toString()).toStringAsFixed(0)}'
                                  .replaceAllMapped(reg, mathFunc),
                              'KES${double.parse(inventoryProduct.cost.toString()).toStringAsFixed(0)}'
                                  .replaceAllMapped(reg, mathFunc), () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                PageTransition(
                                    child: ProductInfoScreen(
                                      user: widget.user,
                                      discPrice:
                                      inventoryProduct.cost.toString(),
                                      userId: widget.user.id.toString(),
                                      id: inventoryProduct.productId.toString(),
                                      shopName: inventoryProduct.company!.name
                                          .toString(),
                                      productPrice: inventoryProduct
                                          .sellingPrice
                                          .toString(),
                                      productTitle: inventoryProduct
                                          .product!.title
                                          .toString(),
                                      productInfo: inventoryProduct.description
                                          .toString(),
                                      productImage: inventoryProduct.product!
                                          .featuredImage!.digitalOceanUrl
                                          .toString(),
                                      inventoryId:
                                      inventoryProduct.id.toString(),
                                      shopId: inventoryProduct.merchantId
                                          .toString(),
                                    ),
                                    type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeft));
                          },
                                  () {
                                ShopService()
                                    .addToWishlist(
                                  inventoryProduct.merchantId.toString(),
                                  widget.user.id.toString(),
                                  inventoryProduct.productId.toString(),
                                  inventoryProduct.id.toString(),
                                )
                                    .then((value) {
                                  setState(() {});
                                  if (value['error'] && value['data'].isNotEmpty) {
                                    Flushbar(
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          bottom: 12.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                      message: value['message'],
                                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                    ).show(context);
                                  } else if (value['error']) {
                                    Flushbar(
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          bottom: 12.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                      message: 'Please try again later!!',
                                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                    ).show(context);
                                  } else {
                                    setState(() {});
                                    Flushbar(
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          bottom: 12.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                      message: 'Added to wishlist!',
                                      duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                    ).show(context);
                                  }
                                });
                              },
                              selectedForYouIndex,
                              isReportForYouClicked,
                                  (){
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedForYouIndex = index;
                                  isReportForYouClicked = true;
                                });
                              },
                                  (){
                                setState(() {
                                  isReportForYouClicked =
                                  false;
                                });
                              },
                                  (){
                                showModalBottomSheet(
                                    isDismissible: true,
                                    enableDrag: true,
                                    isScrollControlled: true,
                                    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (context) {
                                      return SafeArea(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            height: size.height - 80.0,
                                            child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                              child: Column(
                                                children: [
                                                  Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                                                    Container(height: 5.5, width: 100.0, decoration: BoxDecoration(color: AppColors.fontHeaderColor, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
                                                    Container(),
                                                  ]),
                                                  Padding(
                                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                                                    child: Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                                      children: [
                                                        const SmallTextWidget(
                                                          text: "Report",
                                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                                          size: 16.0,
                                                        ),
                                                        InkWell(
                                                          onTap: () {
                                                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                          },
                                                          child: const Image(
                                                            image: AssetImage("assets/icons/cancel.png"),
                                                            height: 26,
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Padding(
                                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
                                                    child: SmallTextWidget(text: "Your report is anonymous", fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, size: 10.0, color: AppColors.fontHeaderColor.withOpacity(0.6)),
                                                  ),
                                                  const SizedBox(
                                                    height: 5.0,
                                                  ),
                                                  FutureBuilder(
                                                      future: fetchFlags,
                                                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                                          return Column(
                                                            children: [
                                                              ListView.builder(
                                                                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                                                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                                                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                                                  physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                                    return Column(children: [
                                                                      InkWell(
                                                                        onTap: () {
                                                                          setState(() {
                                                                            ///Remove product here
                                                                            Flushbar(
                                                                              title: 'Report',
                                                                              message: 'Report submitted, you\'ll see few of this',
                                                                              duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                                                            ).show(context).then((value) => Navigator.of(context).pop());
                                                                          });
                                                                        },
                                                                        child: ListTile(
                                                                          title: Text(snapshot.data[index]['flag'].toString()),
                                                                        ),
                                                                      ),
                                                                      const Padding(
                                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 14.0),
                                                                        child: Divider(
                                                                          height: 2.0,
                                                                          color: AppColors.fontHeaderColor,
                                                                        ),
                                                                      )
                                                                    ]);
                                                                  }),
                                                            ],
                                                          );
                                                        } else {
                                                          return Container();
                                                        }
                                                      })
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }).then((value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    inventoryList.removeWhere((element) => element.id == inventoryProduct.id);
                                    isReportForYouClicked = false;
                                  });
                                });
                              },
                                  (){
                                setState(
                                        () {
                                      ///Remove product here
                                      inventoryList.removeWhere((element) =>
                                      element.id == inventoryProduct.id);
                                      isReportForYouClicked = false;
                                      Flushbar(
                                        title: 'Got it!',
                                        message: 'You\'ll see few of this',
                                        duration:
                                        const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                      ).show(
                                          context);
                                    });
                              },
                                  (){
                                setState(() {
                                  selectedForYouIndex = index;
                                  isReportForYouClicked =
                                  !isReportForYouClicked;
                                });
                              },
                              _isSelected ? Colors.redAccent : AppTaste.whiteThemeColor,
                              _isSelected ? Icons.favorite_rounded : Icons.favorite_outline_rounded
                          );

                        })
                        : VerticalShimmerWidget(context),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        showFloatingCategories ?
        Positioned(
          top: kToolbarHeight,
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Container(
                height: 45.0,
                  width: size.width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.6)
                    )
                  )
                ),
                child: FutureBuilder<List<AllCategoriesModel>>(
                    future: topCategoriesFuture,
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<AllCategoriesModel>> categorySnapshot) {
                      if (categorySnapshot.hasData) {
                        if(categorySnapshot.data!.isNotEmpty){
                          return ListView.builder(
                              physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: categorySnapshot.data?.length,
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                                return Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0, bottom: 5.0, left: 10.0),
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: () {
                                     setState(() {
                                       categoryName = categorySnapshot
                                           .data![index].name
                                           .toString();
                                     });
                                    },
                                    child: Container(
                                      //width: 100.0,
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                      ),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: SmallTextWidget(
                                            maxLine: 1,
                                            text: categorySnapshot
                                                .data![index].name
                                                .toString(),
                                            color: AppTaste.secondaryThemeColor,
                                            size: 14,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              });
                        }else{
                          return  const Center();
                        }

                      } else {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0),
                          child: ListView(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            children: List.generate(5, (index) => CategoryShimmerWidget(context)),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    })
              )
            )) : const SizedBox(),
      ],
    );
  }
```

But the scrollController does not get attached/not working and when I do log print I get that it stays at 0.0. What could I do for this to work?

Comment: Could you please share the whole class?